# What's the easiest way to generate multiple similar scripts or files?

Tags: python, matlab, vim, sed

I've been submitting multiple matlab scripts to a cluster as an array job, which is efficient. But I've been generating each of the scripts manually! For say `x = 1:1000`, I would like to change:

filename = `foo_x.m`

and parameters within the mscript

```
a = x;
b = 'x_1';
c = 'x_2';
```

I.e. the task is to generate multiple files which are exactly the same, except for their values of x. x appears both within the script and the filename.

I have a small amount of experience with python, sed and vim. Any suggestions on the best way to tackle a task like this, or any tutorials out there?

Comment: This sounds strange.  Are you sure there's no way in your cluster software to submit a MATLAB function with a varying parameter?  Or to extract the job number from inside the MATLAB script and use that to select x?  Or to access and modify a shared file with a running value for x?

Comment: Aha yeah these are definitely great suggestions and will make my directories nicer to look in! The way i did it was my natural progression from submitting each (embarrassingly parallel) job via qsub, to submitting them all together in an array job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution in Matlab using [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diary.html):

```
for x = 1:1000
    diary(['foo_' num2str(x) '.m' ])
    disp(['a = ' num2str(x) ';'])
    disp(['b = ''' num2str(x) '_1'';'])
    disp(['c = ''' num2str(x) '_2'';'])
    diary off
    disp(' ')
end
```

If you need file names of the form "foo_0001.m" (i.e. fill numbers with zeros to the left), replace the first line within the loop by

```
    diary(['foo_' num2str(x,'%.4d') '.m' ])
```

Comment: love this thanks. didn't realise matlab had such capabilities

Comment: Oh, but you have to put `disp('')` around every single line you want in the files?

Comment: Yes. `disp` displays its input string on the command window; and `diary` saves to disk whatever is shown on the command window

Answer (score 2):

### Python solution

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

In the following code `template` contains `{0}`. Think of it as placeholder. Using `str.format`, you can replace that with argument with the first argument of the `str.format`.

```
template = '''
a = {0};
b = '{0}_1';
b = '{0}_2';
'''

for x in range(1, 1000+1): # loop from 1 to 1000
    with open('foo_{}.m'.format(x), 'w') as f: # Open file ("w"rite mode)
        f.write(template.format(x)) # render the template string
                                    #  replacing placeholder (`{0}`)
```

Replace `foo_{}.m` with `foo_{:04}.m` if you want filenames look like `foo_0012.m` instead of `foo_12.m`.